# How to create a file inside the `/etc` folder in Linux with C?

Tags: c, linux, permissions

I'm writing a program in C that will have to check a **configuration file** every time it starts to set some variables.

At the first start of the program I suppose there won't be any configuration file, so **I need to create it** (with default settings).

I've been said configurations files of program belongs to the folder `/etc`, more specifically to a particular folder created on purpose for the program itself (i.e. `/etc/myprog`). Here comes the first question I should have asked: is it true? Why `/etc`?

In any case I tried to create that file using this:

```
open("/etc/myprog/myprog.conf", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
```

the `open` returns `-1` and sets `errno` global variable to `2` (i.e. **folder does not exist**). 
If I try to create the file straight inside `/etc` (therefore `"/etc/myprog.conf"` as first argument of the `open`) I get instead an `errno` set to `13` (i.e. **permission denied**).

Is there a way to grant my program permissions to write in `/etc`?

**EDIT:** I see most users are suggesting to use `sudo`. If possible I would have preferred to avoid this option as this file has to be created just once (at the first start). Maybe I should make 2 different executables? (e.g. `myprog_bootstrap` and `myprog`, having to run only the first one with `sudo`)

Comment: Are you running the program as someone with write permissions on that directory?

Comment: `sudo your_exec` ....?

Comment: _[sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/)_ <program> to get privileges

Comment: Only superuser (root) can create files in /etc. If anyone could, the password file would not be safe!

Comment: If the person who invokes your program doesn't have access to `/etc/`, it wouldn't make sense that your program would (that would be a huge security hole...).  You need to run with `sudo` (which has already been mentioned about five times since I started typing this :-) )

Comment: What is your program actually doing? What is `/etc/myfile`? Please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments! @BasileStarynkevitch I edited my question as you suggested!

Comment: @Robb1: Not really, you don't explain the real purpose of your program, and what is that `/etc/myfile` useful to you. Why can't it be e.g. a symlink (to some other file perhaps in `/var/lib` or `/var/cache`). I actually suspect some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that definitely could be a "XY problem"! Do you suggest me to close the question and create a new one? What I want to do is create a configuration file for a program inside the `/etc` folder (as it has been suggested to me, even if I honestly don't really know why `/etc` itself!) This file has to be created only at the first start of the program, or in case it gets deleted manually by the user... in all other cases I just need to read it!

Comment: @Robb1: No, I suggest to edit again your question, and explain in several paragraphs what your program is actually doing and what is that `/etc/myfile` really used for.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a local user config which would be something like `$HOME/.myprogrc` - `/etc` is really for default system-wide configurations that users wouldn't get to do anything to and are typically put there during installation rather than when a program is.

Comment: Can't your program just use default settings without creating the file?

Answer (score 7):

You need root privileges to create a file in `/etc`.  Run your executable with `sudo` in front:

```
sudo executable_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility might be to make your executable [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). Your program would then call very appropriately the [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html) system call.

However, be very careful. Programs like `/bin/login` (or `/usr/bin/sudo` itself) are coded this way, but any subtle error in your program opens a can of worms of security holes. So please be paranoid when writing such a code, and get it reviewed by someone else.

Perhaps a better approach might be to have your installation procedure make `/etc/yourfile` some symlink (created once at installation time to some writable file elsewhere) ....

BTW, you might create a group for your program, and make -at installation time- the `/etc/yourfile` writable to the group, and make your program setgid.
Or even, dedicate a user for your program, and have this `/etc/yourfile` belonging to that user.

Or, at installation time, have the `/etc/myprog/` directory created and belonging to the appropriate user (or group) and being writable to that user (or group).

PS. Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: I'm not sure why you recommend to create a symlink - in places where you're not allowed to create a file, you're very unlikely able to create a symlink.